# viewWillAppear is not being called after clicking the home button

Tags: ios, swift

i have this view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let user = NSUserDefaults()
        let mobileNumber = user.valueForKey("mobileNumber") as? String
        if let mobileNumber = mobileNumber {
            print("mobile number = \(mobileNumber)")
        }else {
            print("no mobile number")
        }
    }


    @IBAction func makePhoneCall(sender: UIButton) {
 if let phoneCall = phoneCall {
            let user = NSUserDefaults()
            user.setValue(phoneCall, forKey: "mobileNumber")
```

when the user clicks on a button, i save the `mobileNumber` in nsuserdefault.

then i click the button, then i open the app again, but problem is that when i open the app agian, i don't bet any message from the `viewWillAppear` even though i am printing in the `if` and in the `else` part.

Comment: Why do you expect `viewWillAppear:` to be called when returning to the app?

Comment: @rmaddy that is what i study, sounds like i am wrong, should i use the app delegate ?

Answer (score 3):

tylersimko is correct that `viewWillAppear(_:)` is not called when the application enters the foreground and that event is instead captured by "application will enter background".

That said, you don't need to observe this from the app delegate but could instead use the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` [notification](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidEnterForeground", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

func applicationDidEnterForeground() {
    // Update variable here.
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

The above code:

1. When your view loads, your view controller registers to have the function `applicationDidEnterForeground()` called whenever the application enters the foreground.
2. The function `applicationDidEnterForeground()` does whatever needs to be done.
3. The view controller unregisters from all notifications when it deallocates to avoid a zombie reference in iOS versions before 9.0.

Given that you are working with NSUserDefaults, you could instead consider observing `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`.

Answer (score 2):

In AppDelegate.swift, make your change in `applicationWillEnterForeground`:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // do something
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your changes in the ViewController, you could set up a function and call it like this:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    ViewController.refreshView()
}
```

Comment: but how can i know that a particular viewcontroller will be on screen? because that app delegate is for all view controllers

Comment: You can write a method in the ViewController that you want to refresh, and then call it in `applicationWillEnterForeground` in AppDelegate.